# Angular2- Getting confused with Observable Catch closure scope

Tags: angular, scope, closures

Wondering if you can give a little assistance. I appear to be getting myself a bit confused when it comes to using `catch` with `Observable`s.

Basically what I'm trying to do is the following:
When my API returns a 403 error, I want to perform some actions on my `TokenStore`, namely, delete the local token and mark the user as unauthenticated. The way I'm trying to do this may be wrong, so please do let me know if there's a better way of accomplishing this.

I'm trying to accomplish this with the following code:

**APIConnector.service.ts** - a single service for API communication methods

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable}     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import {Logger}     from './logger.service';
import {TokenStore} from '../stores/token.store';

@Injectable()
export class APIConnector {

    private _apiUrl:string = 'https://api.sb.zerojargon.com/';
    private _token:string = null;

    constructor(
        private _http:Http,
        private _logger:Logger,
        private _tokenStore:TokenStore
    ) {}

    get(endpoint:String, includes:Array<string>) {
        let includeString = (!_.isUndefined(includes)) ? this._parseIncludes(includes) : '';
        let headers = this._createHeaders();
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this._http.get(this._apiUrl + endpoint + '?include=' + includeString, options);
    }

    post(endpoint:String, formData:Object, includes:Array<string>) {
        let includeString = (!_.isUndefined(includes)) ? this._parseIncludes(includes) : '';
        let body = JSON.stringify(formData);
        let headers = this._createHeaders();
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this._http.post(this._apiUrl + endpoint + '?include=' + includeString, body, options);
    }

    handleError(error: Response) {
        // log out the user if we get a 401 message
        if (error.json().error.http_code === 401) {
            this._tokenStore.destroy();
        }
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }

    private _parseIncludes(includes:Array<String>) {
        return includes.join();
    }

    private _createHeaders() {
        return new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token') });
    }
}
```

In each of my services which use the APIConnector, I have catch methods on the `Observable`s, to run the `handleError` closure. e.g.

```
public createEvent(event:Object) {
    let endpoint = this._endpoint;
    return this._apiConnector.post('clients/'+this.client+'/events', event, this._defaultIncludes)
        .map(res => {
            return this._transformer.map('event', <Object[]>res.json());
        })
        .catch(this._apiConnector.handleError);
}
```

However, this gives the following error:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined

Presumably this is because handleError is a closure. I'm unsure of the best way to deal with this, though.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What if you do  `.catch(error => this._apiConnector.handleError(error))` ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is that you reference the function directly so you lose its context. I mean it's now afunction and a method.

There are two ways to fix this:

- binding the function to this:

  ```
  .catch(this._apiConnector.handleError.bind(this));
  ```

  This approach isn't recommended because you will lose types here. See this link for more details: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/bind.html
- wrapping the call into an arrow function:

  ```
  .catch((error) => {
    this._apiConnector.handleError(error);
  });
  ```

Comment: This answer was correct, with one small adjustment. The catch method requires you return something, so a `return` is required within the brackets.

Comment: You return something if you want to throw a new or the same error: "return Observable.throw(error);". If it's not your case, don't return. The error won't be propagated to another catch or to the second callback of subscribe.

Comment: I had the same issue and this answer solved it. However I like the solution without brackets and without '_apiConnector' way better `.catch(error => this.handleError(error));`