# Angular 2 & RxJs catch function callback binding to 'this' causes http request to be repeated over and over

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5, angular2-http

I have a method for handle our errors from http requests and it looks like this

```
public handleError(err: any, caught: Observable<any>): Observable<any> {

  //irrelevant code removed
  this.logger.debug(err);//example of problem 
  return caught;
}
```

It is invoked like this (example method, but shows the error)

```
  public makeHttpCall() {
    this.http.get("http://api.exmaple.com/getsomedata")
      .map(r=> r.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

The problem with the above code is that when calling `this.logger.debug(err)` in the `handleError` method `this` no longer refers to the class the http call was made from but references the CatchSubscriber.

See here:
[image: example of this]

So i change `.catch(this.handleError);` to `.catch(this.handlError.bind(this))`;

This works, now when i call `this.logger.debug` `this` refers to the correct object. The problem is, the http request gets called over and over and over, 
see here:

[image]

This only happens after applying `.bind(this)`

I can't figure out why this is happening

*********EDIT*********

Change from `.catch(handleError)` to `.catch((a,b)=>handleError(a,b))` fixes the reference of `this` but the http request just gets spammed over and over, but only when the request fails. If the request succeeds it only happens once.

Comment: does this solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227996/angular2-getting-confused-with-observable-catch-closure-scope ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a function with `.catch(this.handleError);` it loses its context `this`. See [Why do I lose the context of this in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382165/why-do-i-lose-the-context-of-this-in-javascript)

Most easily you can fix this by wrapping the function call into a closure.

```
.catch((err, caught) => this.handleError(err, caught));
```

Comment: This does fix the `this` reference but the request still happens over and over.

Comment: Of course, you return the original Observable that threw the error in `handleError()` and `.catch()` operator resubscribes to it. That's what `catch()` does by design https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/catch.md

Comment: Thanks @Martin, I didn't see that "Continues an observable sequence that is terminated by an exception with the next observable sequence." So how do you prevent it from continuing? Returning null will throw and error.

Comment: @StevenYates You prevent it by not using `catch()` operator if you don't need its functionality. So the question is why you're using `catch()` in the first place. Another option is to return a dummy Observable for example `Observable.of(null)`.

Comment: I am using catch to log errors. Maybe I'm not using the correct method, but I just need to log anything that goes wrong with a request. Should I be using another method?

Comment: @StevenYates Then you shouldn't be using `catch()` at all. Use `subscribe()` method instead here http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-subscribe or