# Typescript: accessing public / protected members from abstract class

Tags: angular, typescript

Doing our first big App we have encounter a problem that supposed to be fixed in typescript 2.0+

Having the Abstract class:

```
export abstract class HttpBaseService {
  protected abstract readonly TAG: any;
  protected abstract _state: GlobalState;
  private r = Math.random();

  protected extractData(res: Response) {
    console.log(`${this.TAG}:extractData:`, res.json());
    const data = res.json() || [];
    return data;
  }

  protected handleErrors(error: Response) {
    console.error(`${this.TAG}:handleErrors:`, error);
    console.log(this.TAG);
    console.log(this._state);
    if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) {// Not Authorized
      console.error(`${this.TAG}:handleErrors: NOT AUTHORIZED`, error);
      this._state.notifyDataChanged("logout", error);
    }
    return Observable.throw(error.json());
  }

}
```

and the implementation:

```
@Injectable()
export class AlbumService extends HttpBaseService {
  TAG = AlbumService.name;

  constructor(protected _state: GlobalState,
              private http: Http,
              private auth: AuthService,
              private localStorage: LocalStorageService,) {
    super();
    this._state = _state;
  }

  albums() {
    console.log(`${this.TAG}:albums:`);
    console.log(this._state);
    const ALBUMS_URL = this.albumsUrl();
    const token = this.auth.getToken();
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', `Token ${token}`);

    return this.http
      .get(`${Constants.API_URL}${ALBUMS_URL}`, {headers})
      .catch(this.handleErrors)
      .map(this.extractData);
  }
}
```

When the function handleError from the super class is executed in a sub class has both parameters TAG and _state as "undefined"

Notice that i have test it putting it abstract, protected, public, from the constructor, manually assigning the members, and maybe several others.

I have to be missing something, because in the sub class constructor, i tried calling the handleError method after the assigning of _state and it works as expected, having a value for TAG an a value for _state.

**UPDATE: Reducing the problem to a minimun**

Now i have:

```
export abstract class HttpBaseService {
  protected abstract _state: GlobalState;

  protected handleErrors(error: Response) {
    console.log(this._state);
  }
  protected extractData(res: Response) {
    const data = res.json() || [];
    return data;
  }
}
```

and the implementation:

```
@Injectable()
export class AlbumService extends HttpBaseService {

  constructor(_state: GlobalState,
              private http: Http,
              private auth: AuthService,
              private localStorage: LocalStorageService,) {
    super();
    this._state = _state;
  }

  albums() {
    const token = this.auth.getToken();
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', `Token ${token}`);

    return this.http
      .get(`${Constants.API_URL}`, {headers})
      .catch(this.handleErrors)
      .map(this.extractData);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's related to the problem you're having but `this._state = this._state;` looks redundant - should that be `this._state = _state;`?

Comment: @0mpurdy it was an error form one of the implementations that i tried

Comment: Already tried without being an abstract class and it does not work

Comment: I try like 9 other solutions that include, non abstract extension, constructor in super class, assigning in the constructor of sub class

Comment: Have you tried removing most of the code down to the bare minimum to reproduce the problem? This will make it easier to answer and also in the process you might solve your own problem! [mcve]

Comment: Yes, i already create another class for isolating the problem with just one method that does a console.log and it does not work. I will publish the update @0mpurdy

Comment: Thanks for adding that @alacret however it's very late here - hopefully someone will get this answered before tomorrow otherwise I'll tackle it then!

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `abstract` from the properties:

   ```js
   protected abstract readonly TAG: any;
   protected abstract _state: GlobalState;
   ```
2. `this._state = this._state` should probably be `this._state = _state;`
3. `AlbumService.name` does not appear to be defined anywhere.

So you are assigning *undefined* `this._state` to `this._state`, leaving it *undefined*, and assigning `underfined` `AlbumService.name` to `TAG`.

Comment: Already tried that, i actually put abstract into properties after tried without "abstract" keyword.

Comment: this._state = this._state was an error from one of the times. I fixed now.

Comment: AlbumService.name is the name of the class. It works in the subclass, but not when calling the methods defined in the Super class

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: [Angular 2 & RxJs catch function callback binding to 'this' causes http request to be repeated over and over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149894/angular-2-rxjs-catch-function-callback-binding-to-this-causes-http-request-t)

It turns out that as i'm passing a reference function to .catch and to .map those functions are copied, and the meaning of "this" changes.

So "this" in the function references to the Observable Subscriber. I do not know if this is a design problem but it took me all day to figure out.

So, now my method calls in the Super Class are like this:

```
export abstract class HttpBaseService {
  protected readonly TAG = HttpBaseService.name;
  protected state: GlobalState;

  protected extractData(res: Response) {
    console.log(`${this.TAG}:extractData:`, res.json());
    const data = res.json() || [];
    return data;
  }

  protected handleErrors(error: Response) {
    console.error(`${this.TAG}:extractData:`, error);
    if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) {
      this.state.notifyDataChanged('logout', error);
    }
    return Observable.throw(error.json());
  }

}
```

And i used like this:

```
return this.http
  .delete(`${Constants.API_URL}${ALBUMS_URL}${id}/`, {headers})
  .catch((e, c) => this.handleErrors(e))
  .map(res => this.extractData(res));
```