# Calling local method from catch without using bind angular 2+

Tags: angular

I am trying to call a method from a catch inside my auth service so that if the user is not recognized by the server (401 errors etc) he gets redirected to the login page and info from local storage is deleted.

The problem I am trying to solve is exactly the same as [Angular2- Getting confused with Observable Catch closure scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227996/angular2-getting-confused-with-observable-catch-closure-scope).

However the recommended solution isn't working for me.

If I do `this.handleError.bind(this)` it works.

This - `.catch((err) => {this.handleError(err);});` (which is the recommended solution) doesn't work. I get the following error --

```js
[ts]
Argument of type '(err: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<void>) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
```

here is my handleError method --

```ts
private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    this.forceLogout();
    let errMsg: string;
    console.log(error);
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    this.forceLogout();
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried this right? `.catch(this.handleError.bind(this));`. Should works like that.

Comment: Yep. i have mentioned in my question that it works with bind

Comment: So, in this way? `.catch((err) => this.handleError(err));`. And add an `Observable` return type to your function like:  `private handleError (error: Response | any): Observable<any>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I answered my own question.

I needed to move the return statement out of my handleError method and directly into the catch block like so --

```js
.catch((err) => {
      this.handleError(err);
      return Observable.throw(err);}
    );
```